# I can see all names for a renamed branch on git

Tags: git

I renamed my branch on git repo using these instructions: https://multiplestates.wordpress.com/2015/02/05/rename-a-local-and-remote-branch-in-git/

```
git branch -m new-name
git push origin :old-name new-name
git push origin -u new-name
```

Now when I do 'git branch -a', I do not see the 'old-name' branch. However when I do so on another machine I see both branches. Furthermore, I can 'git checkout' any of them. What did I do wrong? How can I ensure that other people do not see the old-name branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now when I do `git branch -a`, I do not see the `old-name` branch.
>   However when I do so on another machine I see both branches

You have renamed the branch **locally** and you did not removed the old one from the remote.

```
# rename the branch as you did
git branch -m <new name>

# now remove it form the remote and push the new one
git push origin --delete <old_branch>

# push the new name to the remote
git push origin <new branch> 

# now on the other machines fetch with the --prune to remove the old branch locally
git fetch --all --prune
```

---

**NOTE**
If some one checkout this branch locally before the rename, he will still have it locally on his repository as local branch.
You cannot remove local branches by fetching from remote

> How can I ensure that other people do not see the old-name branch?

You have to tell them to delete it. if they have already checked out this branch you cant remove it unless deleted locally.

Comment: My sequence of commands appeared to have worked. I think the semicolon before the branch name is the same as specifying '--delete' option. To make sure I do not see old branches on another machine 'git fetch --all --prune' is enough. This is actually very confusing because when I do 'git branch - a' all of those outdated branches are prefixed with 'remotes/origin', which does not make sense because they are removed from the remote.

Comment: yep, you can use `:` or `--delete` both are the same. and if you fetch without `--prune` they will not be deleted